# Datatables - Store hidden data in each row and use it to render HTML

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've spent several hours trying to figure out a way to do this. I have an array of objects containing data relative to the content of the table. My objects aren't related to the structure of the table (no 1 property per column). I need to store an object in each row so I can use it in the `render` function.

I'm sorry I can't provide code samples, since everything I've tried didn't work. I can't get my head around the working of `row().data()` and `render`. Could anyone explain these to me with an example?

Let's say there is a cell in which I want to spawn a div. This div would depend on the data `state` I'd have stored in the row. If it's at `true`, the render function would generate a `<div class="success>Ok</div>`, else it'd generate `<div class="failure>No</div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the code below for an example. Based on your description, I have added "Toggle" button that toggles state of a new data property `state` that didn't exist in the initial dataset.

```js
var data = [
   {
       "name": "Tiger Nixon",
       "position": "System Architect",
       "salary": "$320,800"
   },
   {
       "name": "Garrett Winters",
       "position": "Accountant",
       "salary": "$170,750"
   }
];

$(document).ready( function () {
   // Initial state
   var g_stateInitial = true;
  
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      "data": data,
      "columns": [
         { "data": "name"},
         { "data": "position" },
         { "data": "salary"},
         { 
           "data": null, 
           "searchable":false,
           "render": function(data, type, row, meta){              
              var state = (data.hasOwnProperty('state')) ? data.state : g_stateInitial; 
              if(type === "display"){
                return (state) ? '<div class="success">OK</div>' : '<div class="failure">NO</div>';
              } else {
                return state;
              }
           }
         },
         { 
           "data": null, 
           "searchable":false,
           "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
              if(type === "display"){
                return '<button type="button" class="btn-toggle">Toggle</button>'
              }
              return data;
           }
         }
           
     ]
     
   });

   $('#example tbody').on('click', '.btn-toggle', function(){     
      var $row = $('#example').DataTable().row($(this).parents('tr'));
      var data = $row.data();
      data.state = (data.hasOwnProperty('state')) ? !data.state : !g_stateInitial; 

      $row
         .data(data)
         .invalidate()
         .draw(false);
   });
  
});
```

```css
.success {
  color:#009900;
}

.failure {
  color:#990000;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a row have an array as data? I tried 
`{
                data: ["nomclient", "idclient"],
                render: function(data, type, row, meta){
                    console.log(data);
                    return 'ui'
                }
            }`

But it says that data is undefined

Comment: @Percee, `row` variable in `render` function contains row data.